# What's the best way to caramelize a large amount of sugar?

Tags: caramel, melting-sugar

I have an African winemaking recipe that calls for caramelizing 4kg of sugar. Each kg is about 5 cups. Most explanations call for at most 1.75 cups, so that would be about 11 batches.

Is there a better way to caramelize larger amounts of sugar?

Comment: Sounds like a big mess. Probably was caramelized in the original vessel traditionally.

Comment: I wonder if you could do it in a pan in the oven

Comment: https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2016/05/dry-toasted-sugar-granulated-caramel-recipe.html (may help)

Comment: A very big pot. Are you making a dry caramel? Wet caramel? I was going to recommend checking out the recipe at the above link. If you were to caramelize the sugar and then make a caramel with it you wouldn't have to take it to as high a temp to get the same caramel flavour.

Comment: https://www.kawalingpinoy.com/caramelize-sugar-microwave/

Comment: Some people make a lot for brewing beer. This thread at HomeBrewTalk.com may help: https://www.homebrewtalk.com/forum/threads/20-lb-of-sugar-and-a-jar-of-yeast-nutrient.114837/